# Trouble calling these methods in my while loop

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, while-loop, queue

I'm trying to create a queue simulation for a restaurant using the following method:

**QueueSim**

```
    public static void queueSim(String filename) {
    System.out.println("=== queueSim ===");
    // Initialization
    ArrayList<String> dataAL = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Server> serverList = new ArrayList<Server>();

    String inputLine;

    // Read data from file into array list
    readDatafile(filename, dataAL);
    
    System.out.println(filename + " is used for this simulation.");
    System.out.println("Start simulation using filename -> " + filename);
    
    inputLine = dataAL.get(0); // first line of input data
    generatePrimarySecondaryServers(inputLine, serverList); //creates primary & secondary servers
    
    
    inputLine = dataAL.get(dataAL.size() - 1);
    int totalMinute = getTotalMinute(inputLine);
    
    System.out.println("\nTotal minute of simulation: " + totalMinute);
    
    int totalCustomers = dataAL.size() - 1;
    System.out.println("The total number of customers in this simulation is " + totalCustomers + ".");
    

    Queue pQueue = new Queue(dataAL.size() - 1); // creates primary queue
    Queue sQueue = new Queue(dataAL.size() - 1); // creates secondary queue
    
    
    int minute = 1;
    
     while (minute != totalMinute) {

        for (int loopCounter = 1; loopCounter < dataAL.size() - 1; loopCounter++) {
            
            inputLine = dataAL.get(loopCounter);
            int minuteArrive = getMinuteArrive(inputLine);
            int minuteForPServer = getMinuteForPrimaryServer(inputLine);
            int minuteForSServer = getMinuteForSecondaryServer(inputLine);
            
            Customer Customer = new Customer(minuteArrive, minuteForPServer, minuteForSServer);
        }
        
        processCustomer(Customer, pQueue, minuteArrive, minute);              
        processPServer(pQueue, serverList, minuteForPServer, minuteArrive, Customer);
        processPWork(serverList, sQueue, Customer);
        
        
        minute++;
        
    }
}
```

I'm specifically having issues trying to get the while loop to work.

```
         while (minute != totalMinute) {

        for (int loopCounter = 1; loopCounter < dataAL.size() - 1; loopCounter++) {
            
            inputLine = dataAL.get(loopCounter);
            int minuteArrive = getMinuteArrive(inputLine);
            int minuteForPServer = getMinuteForPrimaryServer(inputLine);
            int minuteForSServer = getMinuteForSecondaryServer(inputLine);
            
            Customer Customer = new Customer(minuteArrive, minuteForPServer, minuteForSServer);
        }
        
        processCustomer(Customer, pQueue, minuteArrive, minute);              
        processPServer(pQueue, serverList, minuteForPServer, minuteArrive, Customer);
        processPWork(serverList, sQueue, Customer);
        
        
        minute++;
        
    }
```

The 3 methods, **processCustomer**, **processPServer**, **processPWork** tells me certain variables in the argument cannot be resolved. However, if I simply put these methods into the nested for loop, I get the following output in cmd when trying to compile and am unable to make any further inputs without exiting:
[image: output]

Also, I think it doesn't make much sense for those methods to be in the for loop given context to my simulation requirements.

I apologize in advance if I omit any important code as I'm still fairly new to programming. Do let me know so I can edit my question! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You probably want to move your 3 methods in the for-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These variables are defined inside the 'for' loop:

```
        int minuteArrive = getMinuteArrive(inputLine);
        int minuteForPServer = getMinuteForPrimaryServer(inputLine);
        int minuteForSServer = getMinuteForSecondaryServer(inputLine);
```

Therefore, they only exist inside the for-loop, and cannot be accessed outside it.  That's nothing to do with the method calls, it is a consequence of where the variables are declared.  The term for this is 'scope', should you wish to read about it.

Since the loop executes many times, and therefore you assign many different values to those variables, it's not clear to me what you expect to do with them outside the loop anyway.  Which value did you want?